# How to avoid skipping methods of mock/spy

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, testing, powermockito

My target is to get inside the flow of spy method.
I mean, **I don't want to skip "manager.createChange(processId);".**
Actually, I want the test class will take me inside (and then I will do all mockito behavior changes..). For now, I can reach the flow until the method and then the method has been skipped.

I know the code logic may not correct, so please do not focus on that :)

Any help regarding how I suppose to design the test class in order to:

1. Use manager as a mock/spy (control mockito behavior).
2. Can be able to run his methods.

**My test class:**

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class createChangeTest {

    @Mock
    private ProcessRepository processRepository;
    
    @Mock
    private ProcessManager manager;

    @InjectMocks
    private RequestsImpl Requestsimpl;

    Process p = new Process();

    @Before
    public void setUpBefore() {
        ProcessManager manager = spy(new ProcessManager(processRepository));
    }


    @Test
    public void changeRequestTest() {
        Process p = Requestsimpl.createChange(11l);
    }
```

**inside Requestimpl:**

```
@Named
@Transactional
@Component
public class RequestsImpl {

@Inject
    private ProcessManager manager;
    

    public Process createChange(Long processId) {
        Process changeRequest = manager.createChange(processId);
        return changeRequest;
    }
```

Comment: Please add the code for RequestsImpl and how you manage dependencies

Comment: What I mean is if you could add more code of your RequestsImpl class. I need to see the constructor part

Comment: @AndresGardiol what details do you need?
The class is extremely long

Comment: I need to see the class constructor to see how you manage dependencies.

Comment: I think you should add this code on your question by editing the post